# How to implement "normal" ES5 prototypal inheritance in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, prototypal-inheritance, es6-class

I am under the impression that ES6 classes are basically a syntactic sugar around the ES5 objects system.
As I am trying to run React without a transpiler, I figured that I could use just use the old syntax for defining object "classes" that "inherit" from React.Component.

```
    var Board = function(props, state) {
        var instance = {};

        instance.props = props;
        instance.context = state;

        return(instance);           
    };

    Board.prototype = Object.create(React.Component.prototype);

    Board.prototype.render = function() {
        return(
            // ...stuff
        )               
    };
```

But that does not work!

```
react.js:20478 Warning: Board(...): No `render` method found on the returned component instance: you may have forgotten to define `render`
react.js:6690 Uncaught TypeError: inst.render is not a function(…)
```

I found alternatives [in this gist](https://gist.github.com/jquense/47bbd2613e0b03d7e51c), and the following works:

```
    var Board = function(props, state) {
        var instance = Object.create(React.Component.prototype);

        instance.props = props;
        instance.context = state;

        instance.prototype.render = function() {
            return(
                // ...stuff
            )               
        };

        return(instance);           
    };
```

I have also found out that I can use the `React.createClass` helper.

But I still would like to understand why React would not handle classes defined in such a common way. It seems to me that ES6 classes are instanciated before being used. I see no reason why ES5-style classes would not be instanciated as well, with similar results.

Comment: Don't create and return an `instance` variable in the constructor; use `this` instead, and don't return anything. (What you're doing in the first snippet isn't really doing ES5 classes properly.)

Comment: I wish people would not downvote this question. The accepted answer provides some information and a clear example, which I was not able to easily find on the web. It might be a useful question for anyone trying to use React with "old-style" objects, despite any errors that I made.

Comment: You may have a look at this answers: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43529107/how-does-prototypal-inheritance-in-javascript-really-works

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Why is “normal” ES5 prototypal inheritance not supported in React?

It is, although using `React.createClass` is probably your better option. It's just that the code in your question isn't doing the standard ES5 class-like inheritance tasks. In particular:

- You're returning an instance of a plain object, not an instance of `Board`, and so `Board.prototype` isn't used by the object. Normally, a constructor function shouldn't return anything, and should use the object `new` created when calling it, which it receives as `this`.
- You're not giving `React.Component` its chance to initialize the instance.
- You're not setting `constructor` on `Board.prototype` (although I don't know whether React cares; a lot of things don't).

It works if you set it up in the normal way. Here's an ES5 example without `React.createClass`, see comments:

```js
// The component
function Foo(props) {
    // Note the chained superclass call
    React.Component.call(this, props);
}

// Set up the prototype
Foo.prototype = Object.create(React.Component.prototype);
Foo.prototype.constructor = Foo; // Note

// Add a render method
Foo.prototype.render = function() {
    return React.createElement("div", null, this.props.text);
};

// Use it
ReactDOM.render(
    React.createElement(Foo, {
        text: "Hi there, the date/time is " + new Date()
    }),
    document.getElementById("react")
);
```

```html
<div id="react"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: You are right that I was not implementing the 1st example properly. However this had evolved from earlier tries which did not work either, when they should have. Your answer seems to contain some valuable (missing) information such as call to the parent class in the constructor.
I also wonder if `Foo.prototype = Object.create(React.Component.prototype);` should not rather be `Foo = Object.create(React.Component.prototype);`

Comment: @Rolf: Re the question about `Foo` in the comment above: No, it shouldn't. Then `Foo` would be a non-function object, which wouldn't work.